# How do I exclude a character from a range in a character class?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, wildcard

How do I combine the following lines for one character:

```
> ls file[1-5]
> ls file[!3]
```

To produce the same result as:

```
> ls file[1-2,4-5] 
> file1 file2 file4 file5
```

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax with the range is

```
ls file{[1-2],[4-5]}
```

Comment: `file[1-2,4-5]` is already a valid pattern. I think the question is how to specify a single pattern without spelling out each subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

It will certainly vary with the context.  In `zsh`, you can do:

```
$ set -o EXTENDED_GLOB
$ ls file([1-5]~3)
```